# Grid Turns Black

Tags: wpf, windows-8

Every Time I set image to a grid,the image does not appear and a black background appear

```
 private void Clk_Enter(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\Images\Backgrounds\wallpaper-2022265.jpg",UriKind.Absolute);
        myBrush.ImageSource = bi;

        mygrid.Background = myBrush;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call BitmapImage.BeginInit() before you set the UriSource, then call BitmapImage.EndInit() afterward.

```
ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\Images\Backgrounds\wallpaper-2022265.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
bi.EndInit();
myBrush.ImageSource = bi;

mygrid.Background = myBrush;
```

Comment: Cant find such method "windows.UI.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage' does not contain a definition for 'BeginInit'

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this on Windows 8?  You should update the tag as it's a bit different.

Comment: If it is Windows 8, is it a WPF or a 'Metro' app?

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer Just add : "ms-appx" before the URI

```
ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
 BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

 bi.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:/images/wallpaper-2022265.jpg",UriKind.Absolute);

 myBrush.ImageSource = bi;

  mygrid.Background = myBrush;
```

Comment: `ms-appx:` is fine but you don't actually need to have it there.  You can just use UriKind.Relative and then use `/images/wallpaper-2022265.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not using a path relative to your project.  In metro applications you are restricted in how you access the file system.  See a post I made about this [here](http://windows8applicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/).

You can use a project relative URI in Xaml like this:

```
<!--Relative To Project-->
<Image Margin="5" Source="/Images/favicon.ico" Height="100"/>
```

or in code like this:

```
bi.UriSource = new Uri("/images/wallpaper-2022265.jpg",UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: ok what if I want to use image that is not in the solution folder ?

Comment: @A.R In addition to the ones listed in the post linked in my answer, see my SO answer to another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020014/uri-schemes-supported-in-windows-8-apps/12020163#12020163  More specific information on file access restrictions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220751/open-extern-sqlite-database-in-a-windows-8-metro-app/12220852#12220852

Comment: why the background appear black when I pick a photo , do you know ? .. I set a background for the grid by the user choice .. when I choose a photo the background turns black not the image